# How to include SQL Server 2012 in WPF installshield

Tags: sql-server, wpf, sql-server-2012, installshield, setup-project

I created  a wpf application with SQL Server 2012. I am new to WPF and windows applications. The application is working fine on my computer and I know how to make exe of the application. But I don't know how to include the SQL Server and the tables with the application, and make the application work for all other systems.

Can anyone help?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

> I am new in wpf and windows application

But your question is neither of WPF nor windows applications. It is about installers.

> But I don't know how to include the sql and the tables with exe

You do not. YOu make a database project. You tiehr provide a prepared MDF file that you add to the local database (assuming one is installed) or setup scripts.

Nothing here has any relevance to wpf or windows apps so far - installing databases has the same problem on every OS in the las 50 years. Mostly also that unless you run a degenerate edge case (small database for personal use) the database will (a) not be on the same computer and (b) be under control of a dba and (c) your insalling user has no authority to setup a database.

Standard approaches are asking for rthe connection ifnromation then installing the tables via install scripts. Obviouslky during your install check / ask whether a local database SERVER should be installed (sql express) if that is even viable (it has limited features).

Generally: before you make installers you read some documentation. There is a lot you can totally hose up on a computer if you ignore realities of how things should be set up.

Comment: Hi Tom

My ques is how can we include sql setup in install shield while creating the set up

Comment: Well, did you consider - ah - reading documentation? Whenever I check products (and installshield is one) have that. Including a prerequisite is a standard approach and well documented.